# Can we dynamically assign an approver in sharepoint workflow

Tags: workflow, issue-tracking

I am creating a task tracking project wherein the notification should go to the approvers dynamically before they could approve it. Can this be achieved using out of box feature?

Comment: How are you determining who approves the task? It can be done, but it might vary depending on where that information is.

Comment: The approvers would be added in the assigned field of task tracking list

Comment: So while creating the task the user also says who approves the task?

Comment: Yes right. There would be stages of approving and there would be 3 approvers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use OOB Approval process inside the workflow. The approver's information should be stored in some place. The best option is to store it as part of the current item.

After each stage you can change the approver and start another approval process.

I have blogged on how to [Approval Workflow with Dynamic Approvers](http://amalhashim.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/sharepoint-custom-approval-workflow-with-dynamic-approvers-using-sharepoint-designer/)

Answer (score 1):

The [Out of the box approval workflow](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/All-about-Approval-workflows-078c5a89-821f-44a9-9530-40bb34f9f742) has an initiation form that asks whose approval should be requested and creates approval tasks for these users, maybe this will work for you.

You can also develop a custom workflow with SharePoint Designer and, having 3 People fields on your list, create an approval task to each of the field's values.

Comment: Out of box approval workflow might help. But the problem is, there are about 5-6 tasks in the list and the approvers are not same throughout. Is it possible to use out of box approval workflow for different approvers

Comment: You can configure multiple stages for approval, they will happen one after the other but yes, each stage can have a different person approve.