# Workflow Routing in SharePoint 2013 based on a user in a dropdown list on an InfoPath Form

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, infopath

I have 10 entries in my workflow routing in SharePoint 2013. Each workflow routing is for a different user that will approve the workflow (Level 2 Approver).

The person that will submit the form will select this user from a dropdown list on the InfoPath form. When the person submits the InfoPath form, I need the workflow in SharePoint Designer to only use the entry in the workflow routing for the user that is selected in the InfoPath form.

Is this possible?

Comment: yes it is possible. Check this out:https://techbrij.com/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-dynamic-approvers

Comment: Also this to get an Idea:https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118824/can-we-dynamically-assign-an-approver-in-sharepoint-workflow

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps to get your dynamic approval. You can save the selected approver into the same list (As approver) then on Item update you can use that value in the workflow. Kindly refer to the below link with step by step.

https://techbrij.com/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-dynamic-approvers